# Angle hunting problem in an isosceles triangle

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, triangles

Consider an isosceles triangle $ABC$ ($AB=AC$), with points $D, E$ lying on sides $AB, AC$, respectively. Suppose that $\angle BAC=\alpha, \angle EBC=\beta, \angle DCB=\gamma, \angle DEB=\omega$.

Suppose that the value (in degrees) of each of the angles $\alpha, \beta, \gamma, \omega$ is an integer.

a) Prove that $\alpha$ must be divisble by four!

b) Prove it is impossible that exactly three of the angles $\alpha, \beta, \gamma, \omega$ is divisible by three!

Using lots of trigonometry I proved that
$$\cot \omega=\dfrac{2\cos \frac{\alpha}{2}\cos (\alpha-\gamma)}{\sin \gamma(\cos \alpha+\cos2\beta)}-\tan (\alpha+\beta)$$

Can someone help to prove a) and b)? Thans in advance. Maybe with trigonometry (perhaps using my fact)? I would be really thankful if someone would post a solution without trigonometry!

Comment: Where did you get this problem? As stated, neither of those claims are necessarily true.

Comment: It is my own problem I need help with. What are the counterexamples?

Comment: For example, take a triangle with $\alpha = 50^\circ$ and choose $D$ and $E$ so that $\beta = \gamma = 30^\circ$.

Comment: Than $\omega$ is not an integer, so it doesn't work.

Comment: Then $\omega = 30^\circ$.

Comment: No, it is about 29.9. Check with geogebra.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The statements are not true, here is a figure.

[image]